# how to create responsive navigation using html and css?

Tags: html, css

I want to create a responsive navigation it should crate horizontal navigation for desktop. For the table it should display in block. For mobile there should be only menu link when I hover on it, it should display whole menu.

```
<div class = "wrapper">
    <nav class = "menu">
        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li class= "li2"><a href="#">In Cinemas Now</a></li>
            <li class = "li2"><a href="#">Coming Soon</a></li>
            <li class = "li2"><a href="#">On DVD/Blu-ray</a></li>
            <li class= "li2"><a href="#">Showtimes &amp; Tickets</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <div class = "navMob">
        <a href ="#"> menu </a> 
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is code for responsive navigation using html and css

HTML

```
  <!doctype html>
  <html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>CSS Only Navigation Menu</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <ul id="menu">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">About ￬</a>
            <ul class="hidden">
                <li><a href="#">Who We Are</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">What We Do</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Portfolio ￬</a>
            <ul class="hidden">
                <li><a href="#">Photography</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Web & User Interface Design</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Illustration</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </body>
  </html>
```

CSS

```
  /*Strip the ul of padding and list styling*/
  ul {
    list-style-type:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    position: absolute;
  }

  /*Create a horizontal list with spacing*/
  li {
    display:inline-block;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 1px;
  }
  /*Style for menu links*/
  li a {
    display:block;
    min-width:140px;
    height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 50px;
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    color: #fff;
    background: #2f3036;
    text-decoration: none;
  }

  /*Hover state for top level links*/
  li:hover a {
    background: #19c589;
  }

  /*Style for dropdown links*/
  li:hover ul a {
    background: #f3f3f3;
    color: #2f3036;
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 40px;
  }

  /*Hover state for dropdown links*/
  li:hover ul a:hover {
    background: #19c589;
    color: #fff;
  }
  /*Hide dropdown links until they are needed*/
  li ul {
    display: none;
  }

  /*Make dropdown links vertical*/
  li ul li {
    display: block;
    float: none;
  }

  /*Prevent text wrapping*/
  li ul li a {
    width: auto;
    min-width: 100px;
    padding: 0 20px;
  }

  /*Display the dropdown on hover*/
  ul li a:hover + .hidden, .hidden:hover {
    display: block;
  }
```